# Cant change window size in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, size

I have a form in Visual Studio that no matter how small i make it, when i debug it goes back to what it was before. But when I make it bigger than the first width, then it lets me do that. My minimum size is set to 0,0, and inside the form, there is 1 picture, and 6 buttons. Here are some other of its properties:
(this isnt actual code, just a list of properties, stackoverflow made me indent, etc.

```
FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle
Size = 122,420
StartPosition = Manual
Location = 0,0
ControlBox = False
ShowIcon = false
SizeGripStyle = Hide
```

Comment: What's the size of picture and buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the size of a control or the whole form ?
The code below would change the form's size (assuming its named Form1.cs aka the default name for the 1st form created in a ado.net project) to 300 height and 300 width, it does this when the form loads, you could also add a button and use that to change the forms size.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
}
```

Comment: im trying to change the forms size like in the properties menu. I wasn't trying to change it programmatically, but this is my last resort

Comment: can you not change the properties of the form ? 
1 Right  Click on the form (i did it at the top of the gray box)
2 Select Properties
3 Find Size 
http://prikachi.com/images/554/4493554n.png

and if not why not ? or are you saying that you tried this and it fails.

Comment: i figured it out, I forgot that windows had a minimum size that the OS assigns it even if you set your own. Is there anyway to bypass that?

Comment: your form's very minimal size is 132W * 38H, this is for the minimase maximise and close [_][ ][X] buttons.

As for the image inside, if you make it not visible (using .Visible=false;) it will allow you to make the form smaller.